# How to have different table styles in CSS

Tags: css, html

I have different tables in my page which should have different border, cellpadding etc. I can create many classes like,

```
.pad5 td {padding:5px}
```

and then using,

```
<table class="pad5">
```

But if I use 'table' is css, the style is applied to all tables. How can I achieve the result?

Comment: Apply different classes to the different tables. Sheesh! *CSS 101*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

declare classes for each type of styling you want to create, and assign to the `<table>` in the html via the `class` attribute

css

```
.table1 {
    ...
}

.table2 {
    ...
}
```

html

```
<table class="table1">
    ...
</table>

<table class="table2">
    ...
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add an ID to each table and in css make reference with this ID like:

CSS & HTML:

```css
#table1 tr td {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 4px solid #888;
}

#table2 tr td {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 4px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table id="table1">
  <tr>
    <td>first content</td>
    <td>second content</td>
 </tr>
</table>

<table id="table2">
  <tr>
    <td>first content</td>
    <td>second content</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give your tables class names also

Example HTML:

```
<table class="mytable">
    <tr>
       <td>My cell</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table class="anothertable">
    <tr>
       <td>My cell</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Example CSS:

```
.mytable {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.anothertable {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

The first table will have a 1px solid black border and the second table will have a 1px solid red border.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I don't use table at all in CSS it works.
e.g.- .cell {border-spacing:10px}

Answer (score -1):

give each of them seperate ids. classes are for css which will be applied to a bunch of different objects, ids are for css which will be applied to specific objects

```
<table id="first_table"></table>
```

Comment: this can be done with classes too, the downside of id selectors is that you can't have more than one unique id on your html page - therefore style cant be reused